# Поиск слова в строке

Tags: c, строки

Суть задания, нужно в строке, которую взяли из файла найти Первое слово, которое начинается на две буквы, введенные с клавиатуры, затем написать это слово в конец строки.

Я нашел адрес нужного слова, но что делать с этим дальше не понимаю. Спасибо

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

//#define S 50
//#define L 2
int main ()
{

    setlocale (LC_ALL, "RUS");
    
    FILE *file1;
    //char text[S][L];
    char text[50];
    char *textadr;
    file1 = fopen("text.txt", "r+");
    
        while (1)
   {
      // Чтение одной строки  из файла
      textadr = fgets (text,sizeof(text),file1);
      break;
    }

    printf ("\n\nСтрока сейчас такая: %s", text);
    
    char sim[2];
    printf("\n\nВведите 2 символа для поиска: ");
    scanf("%c", sim);
    
    //Ищем слова начинающиеся на введенные символы
    char *poisk= strstr(text, sim);
    printf ("Искомое слово в строке на позиции # %d\n ",poisk-textadr+1);
    
    printf ("Это слово -: %s\n" , textadr+(poisk-textadr)); //не работает   
    
getch();
}
```

Comment: Вы б после strstr проверку бы поставили  - strstr  Return Value
A pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of characters specified in str2, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in str1.

Comment: [man 3 strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) читали?

Comment: сам "strstr" работает, и все ищет, но он показывает позицию найденного. А как зная эту позицию вывести то, что на ней находиться ?

Comment: @Shokerkote, читайте внимательно `char *strstr(const char *haystack, ...)`. `strstr()` возвращает **адрес**, а находится там в точности то, что вы искали. Вот эту строку можете и печатать. `if (poisk) printf("... <%s> в позиции # %d\n", sim, (int)(sim - text));`